# How to get month in MM and date in dd format in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am coding in NodeJs and have to create a filename which have date and time appended. The format should be "metadata_yyymmdd_his.json". I am struggling to get the date in dd and month in MM format. 
Below is the code that I have written as of now.

```
const dateObj = new Date();

const month = (`0${dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1}`).slice(-2);

const date = (`0${dateObj.getUTCDate()}`).slice(-2);

const metadataFileName = 'metadata_' + dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + month + date + "_" + dateObj.getUTCHours() + dateObj.getUTCMinutes() + dateObj.getSeconds() + '.json'
```

How can I get the date and month prepended with 0 if it is single digit? 
EX: if month is April then the result should be 04

Comment: try node-date time library npm

Answer (score 0):

If you're in node, don't try to roll your own datetime parsing/formatting: install and then require something that's been written specifically for that purpose, and has been tested extensively so you can rely on it working properly. A common package for that is [moment.js](https://momentjs.com), using its [.format() function](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/)

```
const now = moment.now();
const formatted = moment().format("MM-DD") // or whatever other formatting you need
```